# two-way search with Hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to make a database search program using a Hash as my db storage.

I can already search the list using member numbers but how would I search using fragments of numbers (so entering `1` would give you `001`, `010`, `011`, `021`, etc...) or fragmented/full usernames (Entering `ni` would give `Nightc||ed` and `Oni`)

my current code is as follows:

```
#rDB by Nightc||ed, ©2015
db = Hash.new()

db["001"] = "Oni"
db["002"] = "Eclipse"
db["003"] = "Saikou"
db["004"] = "Nightc||ed"
db["005"] = "Anime"
db["006"] = "Master"

x = 0
num = db.count

puts "IN:   Member:"
num.times do |pair|
    puts "#{db.keys[x]} | #{db.values[x]}"
    x += 1
end

puts "-------------------
Enter index number:"
i = gets.to_i
i -= 1
system "cls"
puts "IN:   Member:
#{db.keys[i]} | #{db.values[i]}"
sleep
```

Comment: You'd need to iterate over the keys and compare each one (for the IDs). Same for the values for partial names.

Comment: The appropriate data structure is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 1):

First, iterate over the hash.  Within each iteration, use `include?` to search for partial results in the key and/or value.

Here's a way to allow the user to enter either a partial number or partial name:

```
db = Hash.new()

db["001"] = "Oni"
db["002"] = "Eclipse"
db["003"] = "Saikou"
db["004"] = "Nightc||ed"
db["005"] = "Anime"
db["006"] = "Master"

puts "Enter search term"
search_term = gets.chomp.downcase

results = db.select  do |k,v| 
  k.downcase.include?(search_term) || v.downcase.include?(search_term)
end

results.size.times do |x|
    puts "#{results.keys[x]} | #{results.values[x]}"
end
```

Results:

```
Enter search term
 1
001 | Oni


Enter search term
 ni
001 | Oni
004 | Nightc||ed
005 | Anime
```